# EditText: How to enable autosuggest for emails/passwords

Tags: android, android-edittext

What I want to achieve is to autofill user email or password from soft keyboard if he is typing password into `EditText`.

I'm using base `EditText` component and each one is extending some functionality so I have `PasswordField`, `EmailField` etc.

Each of those are setting `InputType` in code. But for some reason soft keyboard is not suggesting me to paste password from saved passwords. Or suggesting email from saved emails.

EmailField:

```
inputTextEditText.inputType = InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS
```

PasswordField:

```
private fun setupInputTypeVisiblePass(isVisible: Boolean){
    inputTextEditText.apply {
        transformationMethod = if (isVisible) null else PasswordTransformationMethod()
        inputType = if (isVisible) InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD else InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to implement the `Autofill` Framework in your IME. Specifically, follow the instructions [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/ime-autofill#configure-ime), and implement the autofill suggestions. You'll need to implement the `onCreateInlineSuggestionsRequest()` method to allow your input fields to show those suggestions